# Element.Parse() Throws error

Tags: c#, xml, dom, linq-to-xml

So I am trying to read XML string like this

```
SaveGrammar[x].Item7 = "<condition><expression value=\"(not empty($20)) and ($20 = '1' or $20 = '2')\" /></condition><string-validity regexp=\".*\" domain=\"all-values\" />"
```

Using this method

```
XElement validation = XElement.Parse(SaveGrammar[x].Item7);
```

The problem is it throws the error below.

```
  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 93
```

I know I can read it in with

```
XmlDocumentFragment validity = docXML.CreateDocumentFragment();
                                        validity.InnerXml = SaveGrammar[x].Item7;
```

However I cant do what I need to with DOM I need to use LINQ. Any ideas how to solve this little problem?

Comment: First of all your xml file is not a valid one and do you want to really parse this xml string or just read it...?

Comment: Here it is from file (I have no control over the file whatsoever)


<tag-constraint Some-Data-Removed-From-Here">
    <condition>
     <expression value="not empty($121) and $121 = true" />
    </condition>
    <string-validity regexp=".*" domain="all-values" />
   </tag-constraint>

Comment: Well, as the exception said: You have **two** root/top-level nodes ("<condition>" and "<string-validity>"), which is invalid - because XElement wants to parse a single element, and you provide it with an XML that is akin to a list of two elements. Surround your xml-string with something like `"<root>" + xmlString + "</root>"` and parse that string instead.

Comment: Why did you remove the `<tag-constraint>` from the string before parsing? If you had left it in, the parsing would have worked, and you could easily extract the child elements in `XElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
string xml = "<root>" + SaveGrammar[x].Item7 + "</root>";
```

Then,

```
XElement validation = XElement.Parse(xml);
```

The error is stating you have more than one root element.  As an xml file can only have one root element, create your own with the above and paste in your multi-elements into it before parsing it.

Comment: Thanks, I just went about it a different way as It needed to be injected as a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xml content **has 2 roots**:

```
<!-- root1 -->
<condition>  
    <expression value=\"(not empty($20)) and ($20 = '1' or $20 = '2')\" />
</condition>
<!-- root2 -->
<string-validity regexp=\".*\" domain=\"all-values\" />"
```

**A properly formatted xml file should contain only ONE root**. As such:

```
<root1>
   <child1>
     <subchild1>.....</subchild1>
   </child1>
</root1>
```

This could easily appended by **adding a 'parentroot'** to the content, making the 2 roots nest under the new parentroot as such

```
<parnetroot>    
    <!-- root1 -->
    <condition>  
        <expression value=\"(not empty($20)) and ($20 = '1' or $20 = '2')\" />
    </condition>
    <!-- root2 -->
    <string-validity regexp=\".*\" domain=\"all-values\" />"  
</parnetroot>
```